# Which JAXB version was used in Java 8?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, jaxb

JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding) has been publised as Maven artifacts although it was bundled with JREs until Java 8 (and Java 9/10 with an option).

My question here is: Which JAXB version on Maven Central corresponds to Java 8's bundled version? (And, also for Java 9/10's under a feature option?)

I'm seeing in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api :

- 2.2.* (~ 2.2.12)
- 2.3.0
- 2.3.1
- 2.4.0-* (under development)
- (3.0.0 to be `jakarta.xml.*`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as Java 8:

```sh
$ $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/bin/xjc -version
xjc 2.2.8-b130911.1802
```

which is documented [here](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch02.html) specifying the Maven coordinates:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-bom</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.8</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

although

```xml
          <dependency>                                                          
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>                                   
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>                                   
            <version>2.2.8</version>                                            
            <scope>provided</scope>                                             
          </dependency>
```

is accurate for Java 8.  For Java 9+, the latest available (as you observed) is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer. I was not able to find the reference...

Comment: In 2023, I managed to run a legacy Java 8 application with `2.2.11` version.